# Database structure: Finding and marking similar entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am not sure if my problem has a kind of name, so I can search for it, but here is it anyway:
I have a picture database, very simple:

> ID | PicturePath | SomeMetaData

Some of the pictures are very similar, but not the same. I want to be able to mark that. So for example if PicA is similar to PicB it should be written down somewhere. I have accomplished that by simply creating another table:

> ID1 | ID2

So, if I write in that table PicA on the left and PicB on the right, I can query that table for similar entries. So far so good. The problem I have is, that I will have a lot of these connections and sometimes these are not restricted to two pictures. So for example PicA might be similar to PicB, but PicB might be similar to PicC also. If I query my second table while displaying PicA, I will only get a similar entry with PicB. What I want is not only to find PicB, but also PicC (which is not directly connected to PicA).
I hope you understand.

My questions are:

- What is the best database structure for that kind of problem?
- How can I query (via SQL) all connected pictures? It seems to me, that this must be done by a kind of endless loop... I really don't know where to start.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my simple English.

All the best
Sebastian

Comment: If A is similar to B and B is similar to C, is A similar to C?  It is much easier if it is.  But I would not expect this 'transitivity' to necessarily apply to pictures.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably investigate the database architectural pattern of "Many-to-Many" relationships.

http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/

Answer (score 1):

If A is similar to B and B is similar to C, is A similar to C?  Assuming that it true, I suggest an extra table:

```
CREATE TABLE Similars (
    similar_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    picture_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX(picture_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When you decide that A is similar to B, look in `Similars` for A or B; if you find such, then make sure there are entries for A and B with the same Similar_id.

Step 1
If neither is in the table, add one of them and get the `similar_id` (See `LAST_INSERT_ID()`).
Else you will have discovered a `similar_id`.

Step 2
Insert the other one.

It gets messier if both A and B are in the table with different `similar_ids`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it. But why an AutoIncrement on the similar_id? If I find another conncetion, I should be able to add a new row in that table with an existing similar_id, no?

Comment: Correct.  The `similar_id` ties all the "similar" pictures together.  If you `INSERT` without specifying `similar_id`, a new `AUTO_INCREMENT` value will be generated.  When adding another picture, specify the `similar_id` to tie it to the existing one(s).